# OS X 10.10 Yosemite install Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am trying to install rails on my OS X 10.10 Yosemite i get these errors:
I already install XCode Command Line Tools and Homebrew and sill having  problems.

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150908-43862-19795mu.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Nitzan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Nitzan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
Nitzans-MBP:~ Nitzan$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have installed both rbenv and rvm on your machine. Choose something one and delete another, or delete both and install again the preferred one on a clean table. For simplicity, I would keep rvm, check its site: https://rvm.io/.
Cheers!

**UPDATE**: Now it seems you have one more installed ruby, now via `homebrew`. Remove it too. The point of using RVM is that for your projects you need multiple versions of ruby and make only RVM manage your current ruby, don't use any other rubies (system/homebrew).

RVM crash course:

1. `rvm current` - show your currently used ruby and gemset (if
   any). This is very important information, so important, that I
   advice you to put it into your shell prompt (if you do a lot of ruby
   programming), so when you run any shell command you'd know which
   ruby/gemset pair you're using. Use `rvm-prompt` command to put it
   into your shell (just google for "customize shell prompt" on how to
   do that, I won't delve into this topic here).
2. `rvm requirements` - install all needed requirements for compiling
   ruby on your platform (this should have been done automatically when
   you run `rvm install <ruby version>`)
3. `rvm list` - will list all your installed rubies and show which
   one is default and which one is you're currently using.
4. `rvm list known` - will show all recommended versions of ruby you
   can install, look at the MRI section for now, you don't need
   everything else.
5. `rvm install <ruby-version` - obviously, install ruby of some version.
6. `rvm use <ruby-version>@<gemset>` - switch to some `<ruby-version>`
   and, optionally `<gemset>`. If your directory contains `.ruby-version` and/or `.ruby-gemset` files (see below) you can use the following trick: `rvm use .` - will make RVM pick up settings defined in those files for your current directory.

So, that's what I do when I'm not sure if I use correct ruby:

```
~/projects ♥ rvm current
ruby-2.2.1
~/projects ♥ rvm use ruby-2.2.0@myapp
Using /Users/alexey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0 with gemset myapp
~/projects ♥
```

You can make `rvm` automatically switch ruby versions and gemsets if you place in the root of your project special files `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` (note the `.` in the front of filename) and put your ruby version to `.ruby-version` and your gemset to `.ruby-gemset`, like this:

```
ruby-2.1.4@active_interaction in ~/projects/active_interaction on master ♥ cat .ruby-version 
ruby-2.1.4
ruby-2.1.4@active_interaction in ~/projects/active_interaction on master ♥ cat .ruby-gemset 
active_interaction
ruby-2.1.4@active_interaction in ~/projects/active_interaction on master ♥ cd ..
ruby-2.2.0@pgm-rails2 in ~/projects ♥ cd -
~/projects/active_interaction
ruby-2.1.4@active_interaction in ~/projects/active_interaction on master ♥
```

Note how ruby version in prompt is changing while I switch directories.

It's also useful to commit `.ruby-version` file to make sure everyone on the project is using the same ruby and **not** to commit `.ruby-gemset` since it may interfere with some custom settings of other developers (if they have a gemset with another name, or just don't use any gemsets at all).

Now, what you need to do now:

1. Install your desired ruby version via rvm.
2. Go to your project folder and prepare `.ruby-version` and (optionally) `.ruby-gemset` file.
3. Switch to these versions and make sure you switched correctly.
4. Now, you can run any commands you want, rvm will use your desired ruby.

Comment: Reload your terminal (just open a new tab) and try again. Please, update your error, because at least some output should change, since you have deleted .rbenv (you shouldn't have any lines containing `.rbenv`). If you still do, remove it by hand via `rm -rf ~/.rbenv`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. It turned out that even though I had Development tools installed I didn't agree the Terms and conditions.

Try to run 'gcc' command. In my case I got this message

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please
>   re-run as root via sudo.

Re-running the same command with sudo did the trick.